# Emacs - set mark on edit location

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs23, dot-emacs

I want emacs to add last edit location to the mark ring, so I can jump back to previous edit locations.

Ideally this would only mark **one** edit location per line. When I edit another line, the last edit location on that line would be added to the ring, and so forth.

I'm not familiar with Lisp to implement this myself. If anyone knows of a plugin or can kindly provide a solution that would be great! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Session.el](http://emacs-session.sourceforge.net/) provides this functionality bound to "C-x C-/" or `session-jump-to-last-change`.

Session dos it per buffer.  I'm unaware of anything that does it globally.

Comment: hmm.. for some reason on "`C-x C-/`" I get `C-x C-_ is undefined` but after re-binding it to another key it seems to work. I'll give this a try next few days. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can install a package [goto-last-change](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/goto-last-change.el) which allows you to jump sequentially to the buffer undo positions (last edit locations).

Comment: Thanks Oleg. I do use goto-last-change. It's great but it doesn't behave as I'd like beyond the very last edit location.

Answer (score 0):

I implement a similar function,  by recording 2 file's last edit locations(not per buffer),  and cycle them when requested. Somewhat like how eclipse does(but less powerful, only 2 file's are recorded)

[emacs-last-edit-location](http://shenfeng.me/emacs-last-edit-location.html)

the code:

```
;;; record two different file's last change. cycle them
(defvar feng-last-change-pos1 nil)
(defvar feng-last-change-pos2 nil)

(defun feng-swap-last-changes ()
  (when feng-last-change-pos2
    (let ((tmp feng-last-change-pos2))
      (setf feng-last-change-pos2 feng-last-change-pos1
            feng-last-change-pos1 tmp))))

(defun feng-goto-last-change ()
  (interactive)
  (when feng-last-change-pos1
    (let* ((buffer (find-file-noselect (car feng-last-change-pos1)))
           (win (get-buffer-window buffer)))
      (if win
          (select-window win)
        (switch-to-buffer-other-window buffer))
      (goto-char (cdr feng-last-change-pos1))
      (feng-swap-last-changes))))

(defun feng-buffer-change-hook (beg end len)
  (let ((bfn (buffer-file-name))
        (file (car feng-last-change-pos1)))
    (when bfn
      (if (or (not file) (equal bfn file)) ;; change the same file
          (setq feng-last-change-pos1 (cons bfn end))
        (progn (setq feng-last-change-pos2 (cons bfn end))
               (feng-swap-last-changes))))))

(add-hook 'after-change-functions 'feng-buffer-change-hook)
;;; just quick to reach
(global-set-key (kbd "M-`") 'feng-goto-last-change)
```