# Cycling through cursor positions

Tags: emacs

In Vim I am able to go to previous positions that the cursor has been at. 
moreover I can go back and forth in the list of positions (`C-o` for backward tracing and `C-i` for forward tracing).

Is there a similar functionality in emacs?
`C-u C-SPC` only goes backward in the list.

Comment: Take a look at the `mark-ring`. It's just a cyclical buffer, so it's certainly possible

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102405/emacs-set-mark-on-edit-location help?

Comment: See also [How to move forward and backward in Emacs' mark ring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393834/how-to-move-forward-and-backward-in-emacs-mark-ring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/pointhistory.el .

Citation from the in-file documentation:

Provides two rings `pointhistory-ring` and `pointhistory-auto-ring` for remembering positions of point.
If a command moves point over a long distance the previous point position is stored in `pointhistory-auto-ring`.
You can return to these point positions by the command `pointhistory-auto-backward` (bound to <kbd>M-S-up</kbd>). This is most useful if you accidently moved point and want to return to the previous position.

If you want to remember a point position for later use you can call `pointhistory-point2ring` (bound to <kbd>M-+</kbd>).
Press <kbd>M-up</kbd> or <kbd>M-down</kbd> to rotate through the stored point positions.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Having a separate ring from the marks is a plus!

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is an old post, but I just finished a package that may do what you want, called footsteps. It's similar to the functionality you describe in vim, but it's not identical.

For one, vim's forward/backward tracing functionality doesn't seem to have a density limit, where footsteps attempts to prevent excessively dense cursor positions (or steps) in its position history (or step-ring). If you prefer it to log densely, you can customize the setting 'footsteps--min-lines-before-step'. Giving it a value of 1 should make it behave similar to vim.

Another difference between the two is that footsteps only logs line numbers. It doesn't log the positions within the lines. Using it to navigate will always take you to the beginning of a line.

Vim and footsteps also handle what I would call branching or cyclic navigation differently, but a full description of the behavior of each of them is complicated. The behavior of footsteps is explained extensively in the README.md though.

The last difference (that I'm aware of), is that vim will retain its history across multiple sessions. Footsteps does not do this.

If you would like to try it, it can be found at the following link: https://gitlab.com/jdavisclemson/footsteps.

Summary Description:

> This package provides a way to quickly retrace your "footsteps" when navigating a project.
> It maintains a ring of automatically-logged previous locations called "footsteps", or "steps", for short.
> The steps are logged "intelligently", based on certain settings, which are customizable.
> The steps are stored in the step-ring, which can be conceptualized as a trail of footsteps.

If you choose to use the package, I would strongly recommend reading the entire README.md for more details about how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles) then you can use command `icicle-goto-marker` to cycle among such positions. By default, it is bound in *Icicle* mode to `C-- C-SPC` (`C-SPC` with no prefix argument sets the mark).

You can type text matching some of the text near such positions, to narrow the cycling candidates. You can sort the candidates in different ways, so you cycle in different orders. And you can go to any position directly, without cycling, by matching text at it.

In Emacs there are two kinds of such rings of positions:

- The `global-mark-ring` - a single ring with one position in each marked buffer.
- The `mark-ring` - a per-buffer ring. That is, each buffer has an associated `mark-ring` of positions within that buffer.

The **Icicles** command for navigating among positions on the `global-mark-ring` is `icicle-goto-global-marker`. By default, it is bound in *Icicle* mode to `C-- C-x C-SPC` (`C-x C-SPC` with no prefix argument pops the global mark).